# no camerainfo kinect

Tags: kinect, openni-kinect

[image: Rosanswers logo]

I have been trying to use fast plane detection(http://www.ros.org/wiki/fast_plane_detection) with Kinect disparity map data.
This package expects cameraInfo to be available to detect the dominant planes. But I have not been able to get the camerainfo from the kinect.
Though rostopic list shows the presence of topics /camera/rgb/camerainfo and /camera/depth/camerainfo , these topics remain empty.

rostopic echo /camera/depth/camerainfo and also /camera/rgb/camerainfo donot give any information.

Is there any reason these topics are Null and is there a way to get these topics to the package ?

PS: I have been using Openni kinect package to interface kinect and i am able to visualize kinect 2d/3d data in rviz.

---

[Originally posted](https://answers.ros.org/question/12120/no-camerainfo-kinect/) by [enschulfer schmidt](https://answers.ros.org/users/1452/enschulfer-schmidt/) on ROS Answers with karma: 23 on 2011-11-28

Post score: 0

Answer (score 0, accepted):

[image: Rosanswers logo]

Check Patrick Bouffard's answer a little ways down [here](http://answers.ros.org/question/299/getting-the-calibration-parameters-of-the-kinect)

---

Originally posted by [phil0stine](https://answers.ros.org/users/639/phil0stine/) with karma: 682 on 2011-11-30

This answer was **ACCEPTED** on the original site

Post score: 0

---

#### Original comments

**Comment by [enschulfer schmidt](https://answers.ros.org/users/1452/enschulfer-schmidt/) on 2011-11-30**:
thank you. subscribing to one of the topics made the camerainfo available.